# creating/parsing JSON properly

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arduino, google-cloud-functions

I have an ESP8266 capable of reading temperature and humidity. The idea is to upload these readings to a Firebase database and once this data is uploaded take some action using Firebase's function triggers.

I have an Arduino code that uploads data from an ESP8622. Data uploaded is a timestamp, sensor id, temperature, and humidity. It is as follows:

```
void updateDatabase(String &temp, String &humidity, String &temp_feeling)
{

     String path = "/Measurements";
     String SensorID = "1";
     timeClient.update();
    // timeClient.setTimeOffset(3600);

    long timeStamp = timeClient.getEpochTime();
    json.clear().set("id",DEVICE_ID);
    json.set("timestamp",(String)timeStamp);
    json.set("temperature",temp_feeling);
    json.set("humidity",humidity);

    mostrarJSON(json);

    if (Firebase.pushJSON(firebaseData, path,json))
    {
      Serial.println("PASSED");
      Serial.println("PATH: " + firebaseData.dataPath());
      Serial.println("TYPE: " + firebaseData.dataType());
      Serial.println("ETag: " + firebaseData.ETag());
      Serial.print("VALUE: ");
      printResult(firebaseData);
      Serial.println("------------------------------------");
      Serial.println();
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("FAILED");
      Serial.println("REASON: " + firebaseData.errorReason());
      Serial.println("------------------------------------");
      Serial.println();
    }

}
```

This JSON is uploaded to a Firebase database. Result of the uploaded data is as follows:

Firebase functions have this code to process the latest measurement uploaded.

```
exports.onDataAdded = functions.database.ref('/Measurements').onWrite((change,context)=>{

    const snapshot = change.after;
    const val = snapshot.child("").val()
    console.log(val)
    const temperature = snapshot.child("").child("temperature").val()
    const humidity = snapshot.child("").child("humidity").val()

    console.log(`New data received : temp : ${temperature}, humidity : ${humidity}`)

    takeActionSensorUpdate(temperature,humidity)
    return null
})
```

Result of the code on Firebase console is this:

[image]
And the console output is:

[image]
I have some questions:

- Am I building the JSON object properly on the Arduino code? should I create my own node name instead of using a random unique id for each measurement? If so, how can I do it?
- Why am I printing several instances of the database if I am triggering the code only when I receive a new upload from the ESP8266?
- As you can see on the console output appears null in temperature and humidity data. I guess this is because I have an automatic random id for each new measurement added under /Measurements as it can be seen on the object uploaded to the database. How can I change the code on Firebase functions to get values I want, in this case, temperature and humidity?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Arduino but I think the following will answer your questions.

> Am I building the JSON object properly on the Arduino code? should I
>   create my own node name instead of using a random unique id for each
>   measurement? If so, how can I do it?

As I said, I cannot answer from an Arduino Library perspective (I guess you use this [library](https://platformio.org/lib/show/6398/Firebase%20Arduino%20based%20on%20WiFiNINA)), but letting the database generating a new child location using a unique key (i.e. a "node name" in your question) is very standard and as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push) (JavaScript SDK for example), it is "**the most common pattern for adding data to a collection of items**".

> Why am I printing several instances of the database if I am triggering
>   the code only when I receive a new upload from the ESP8266?

This is because you trigger your Cloud Function at the level of the `Measurements` node.
See below how to trigger it for one specific sub-node of `Measurements`.

> As you can see on the console output appears null in temperature and
>   humidity data. I guess this is because I have an automatic random id
>   for each new measurement added under /Measurements as it can be seen
>   on the object uploaded to the database. How can I change the code on
>   Firebase functions to get values I want, in this case, temperature and
>   humidity?

Same reason than above: `change.after` represents the data of the `Measurements` node (after the triggering event). It does not represent the data of one of its children. In addition by doing `snapshot.child("")` you are getting a `undefined` value because you pass an empty string to `child()`. Here is a Cloud Function code that will do the trick:

```
exports.onDataAdded = functions.database.ref('/Measurements/{pushId}').onWrite((change,context)=>{

    const afterData = change.after.val();
    console.log(afterData)
    const temperature = afterData.temperature;
    const humidity = afterData.humidity;

    console.log(`New data received : temp : ${temperature}, humidity : ${humidity}`)

    takeActionSensorUpdate(temperature,humidity)  //Double check if this is not asynchronous. If yes you need to wait the asynchronous action is done before returning
    return null
})
```

As you will read in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events), we are specifying a path component with a wildcard (surrounded by curly brackets). In other words `ref('/Measurements/{pushId}')` matches any child of `/Measurements`.

Comment: it works, thank you very much!

Comment: sure I just did! Just one last question : how do you convert const temperature and const humidity to float values I can work with , for example, to compare to other numbers? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a look at https://gomakethings.com/converting-strings-to-numbers-with-vanilla-javascript/.